# breaking out of an infinite while loop by getting inputs from the user

Tags: python, embedded, firmware

I'm trying to have an infinite loop run forever and continuously send data. but when the user presses a button on his keyboard it will break out of it. I tried the code below, but it will send data once then ask for your input and so on. Is there a way to have use inputs from the keyboard as an interrupt without asking for the input of the user each time the data is sent?

example code:

```
while 1:
    m = input("press 's' to srart\npress 'n' to stop\n")
    
    if m == 's':
        print("Display") 
    elif m == 'n':
        break
```

Comment: Aside: Use `while True:` not `while 1:`

Comment: Use the `keyboard` module to check for keypresses without waiting.

Comment: what about Control-C?

Comment: You have marked this [embedded] so the nature of your hardware and in particular the "keyboard" is unknown.  There again you have marked it Python so is this really "embedded"?  You probably need to describe your platform.  Perhaps you should tag this [embedded-linux] instead?

Comment: I see that you user "embedded” and “firmware” tags. Are you using Linux? If you do you could read directly the char driver

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use packages, you can import keyboard

```
pip install keyboard
```

and do something like this:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    # do something
    if keyboard.is_pressed("n"):
        print("n pressed, ending loop")
        break
```

Then you can add your own logic where 's' will do what you want it to.

Comment: `keyboard.is_pressed("n")` is true only if the key is pressed _right now_, not if it was pressed _previously_.  If the "do something" code takes a long time to execute, it's possible that the user will have pressed the key during that time but the key is not pressed anymore by the time the code checks for it.

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea .is_pressed() worked that way. Would .read_key() be a better implementation?